# Problem with the folder structure and dependencies

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have the following initial situation:

Our tests refer to a store that is available in multiple languages via country dropdown.
Depending on the country, the store has different features and therefore also different tests.

I have two problems here. The first is the folder structure

In order not to have a separate repo for each country, we would like to separate the test specs for the stores by folders.
But since the PageObjects are identical, I would like to define them only once, so that the test specs can access them.
However, it does not work as I imagine it.

Here is my idea of the folder structure in Cypress:

```
cypress-automation
    cypress
        fixtures
        integration
           shops
              shop_de
                  sample-tests.spec.js
              shop_en
                  sample-tests.spec.js
              shop_es
                  sample-tests.spec.js
        plugins
              index.js
        support
           pageObjects
              samplePageObject.js
           index.js
           commands.js
        node_modules
        cypress.json
        package-lock.json
        package.json
```

However, it doesn't work because Cypress misses the PageObjects. The following error occurs:

```
Error: webpack compilation error
./cypress/integration/shops/shop_en/sample-tests.spec.js

Module not found: Error: Unable to resolve '../support/pageObjects/samplePageObject.js' in 'C:\users\users\desktop\cypress-automation\cypress\integration\shops\shop_en'.
```

The second problem concerns the `index.js`
there I have to add a country switch in the `beforeEach` method, because the URLs of the stores are identical and the store can only be changed via dropdown.
Unfortunately I don't know how to integrate the `index.js` into the store folder, so that the `sample-tests.spec.js` access a specific `index.js` instead of a global one. Alternatively, I would have to adjust the `beforeEach` method in each `sample-tests.spec.js` but with so many test specs I find that impractical.

is that even possible, the way I imagine it?

EDIT:
@Fody

i did it exactly as you said. However, now I get an error:

```
PageObjects_homePage__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_.HomePage is not a constructor
```

here is an example from my code how i included it:

```
import { HomePage } from "@PageObjects/homePage";
```

the constructor looks like this

```
const homePage = new HomePage();
```

HomePage Class:

```
class HomePage {

  testMethod() {
   testcode()
  }
}
export default HomePage;
```

Comment: `C:\users\users\desktop\cypress-automation\cypressintegration\cypress-automation\shop_en` - that does not look anything like the folder structure you describe. Can you specify where either `shop_en.js` or `shop_en/index.js` is located?

Comment: i edited my post. hope its better to understand now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part one, set up a webpack alias to make it easy to import from anywhere in the intergration folders, any level nesting.

Add the package [Cypress Webpack Preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor), following their instructions

- `npm install --save-dev @cypress/webpack-preprocessor`
- `npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-loader webpack` - if not already installed

or with yarn

- `yarn add -D @cypress/webpack-preprocessor`
- `yarn add -D @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-loader webpack` - if not already installed

**cypress/plugins.index.js**

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor');

console.log('__dirname', __dirname)  // __dirname is cypress/plugins

module.exports = (on) => {
  const options = {
    webpackOptions: {             
      resolve: {                 
        alias: {                     
          '@PageObjects': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../cypress/support/pageObjects')              
        },             
      },         
    },     
    watchOptions: {},
  };

  on('file:preprocessor', webpack(options));
};
```

**cypress/integration/shops/shop_de/sample-tests.spec.js**

```js
// resolves any level of nesting
import {MyPageObject} from '@PageObjects/samplePageObject.js'  
...
```

**cypress/integration/shops/shop_de/bavaria/sample-tests.spec.jbs**

```js
// same import after move to sub-folder
import {MyPageObject} from '@PageObjects/samplePageObject.js'  
...
```

Comment: sounds good. I will try. is there a way that my existing import commands are automatically rewritten to the new pattern? 
so from `import CartPage from "../support/pageObjects/cartPage";` to your proposal or do I have to adjust everything manually?

Comment: i update my initial post with a hint for you

Comment: That's a different problem. The import should be the same as you used previously, except now the path string starts with `@PageObjects/`.

Comment: I have found the error. The { } were unnecessary